# How in notepad++ find/replace text between slashes?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to find the text between the second and fourth slashes in a path like `/folder/subfolder-1/subfolder-2/subfolder-3`? I’m trying to replace this with something like `/folder/new-folder/subfolder-3`.

The most important for me is to be able to find the part after the *n*-th slash.

I tried the regex `/((.*?)/){3}`, but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Match resetter `\K` meta-character you are able to do it in a simpler way.

Find:

```
/.*?/\K(.*?/){2}
```

Replace with:

```
new-folder/
```

Comment: or with use of negation: [`/[^/]*/\K[^/]*/[^/]*/`](https://www.regex101.com/r/fnDFdA/1)

Comment: Perfect!! That is working for me.
Thank you.
Could you please just explain me that? How it's working?

Answer (score 2):

One way you could to it is by using this string in the pattern to replace

```
(/.+?)(/.+?){2}(/\S+)
```

And use this one in your pattern to replace it with

```
$1/new-folder$3
```

From your string:

```
/folder/subfolder-1/subfolder-2/subfolder-3
```

- `(/.+?)` will match `/folder` as **$1**
- `(/.+?){2}` will match `/subfolder-1/subfolder-2` as **$2** *(not used)*
- `(/\S+)` will match everything that isn't a space, in this case`/subfolder-3` as **$3**

Leaving you room to insert your *new-folder* in-between.

Comment: That is highlighting till the end of the line, How can I just mark till the slash?

Comment: Instead of `(/.+)`, for the last parameter, use `(/.+?/)`, if the section you want to capture as the $3 ends by a `/`.

Comment: I've updated the code, by replacing the last parameter by (/\S+), it should be closer to the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To find text between second and forth slash you can use the regex `^(/[^/]*/)([^/]*/[^/]*)` then you can reference to the text between slashes with `\2` when replacing the text.

To keep the text before the slashes you can enter something like `\1myNewTextBetweenSlashes2and4`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's highlighting from 3th slash till the end of the document.
So it means that in next line it's highlighting also text before slash, and on first line all text after slash too.

Comment: Yes it highlights text before the slash, but you can enter the text before the slash again when replacing with `\1`. If your line starts with slashes you can add `^` at the beginning to not match on later slashes.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I just mark till the slash?

- Find what: `(/[^/]+/)[^/]+/[^/]+`
- Replace with: `$1new-folder`

Answer (score 0):

`{2}` indicates 2 levels after first level will be repalced by `new-folder`

Find:

```
(\/.*?\/)(.*?\/){2}(.*)
```

Replace:

```
$1new-folder/$3
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XIA3IN/3

Comment: That is highlighting till the end of the line, How can I just mark till the slash?

Comment: Try this: `(\/.*?\/)(.*?\/){2}(\S+\b)`

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ Find by this:

```
(/[^/]+)(?:/[^/]+/[^/]+/)(.*)
```

And Replace by this:

```
\1\/new-folder/\2
```

Make sure that: .matches newline is not checked

Comment: That is highlighting till the end of the line, How can I just mark till the slash?